# executing external JS which require live update (with CSP policy)

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I'm having some trouble with setup an external JS file with live update. 
(just update time)

It was all working until i implemented CSP policy (with no 'unsafe-inline')

Although the JS is not inline,  it actually requires setting a div called "sitetime" (which counted as inline)

I've tried to use doc.write (as my auto update cp year works), but it can't use for live update.

My JS code: (Amazon S3 + Cloudfront)
https://general-s3.cdn.stevenz.net/static/self/default.js

My website:
https://stevenz.xyz

Please give me any advice... (since I'm running out of options)

Thank you

Comment: Your CSP is complaining about `<script data-pagespeed-no-defer>` on line 72, not `default.js`.

Comment: Also, change `setTimeout("siteTime()", 1000);` to `setTimeout(siteTime, 1000);`

Comment: Hi, @Sean Denny    the default.js is not complaining because i removed it... it just refuses to load since it's (still) embed inline, (with div =sitetime)

Comment: Add `sha256-zkXW1v0+HwSD/58JJyc+Bx+Giv9GZBSQIZitSeQCHmA=` an additional source expression for your `script-src` directive. But even once you make than change, you’re still going to get a CSP error unless you make the change to `setTimeout(siteTime, 1000);` that @SeanDenny pointed out